# How to get currently visible x- and y-axis range with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I am creating a chart using [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart).
I see methods  `chart.getLowestVisibleXIndex()` and `chart.getHighestVisibleXIndex()` to get the currently visible x-axis range.

But I need to get the currently visible y-axis range as well. Is that possible and if yes how can I do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is a pretty easy way to do that. All you need is an instance of your chart and it's `ViewPortHandler`.

The `ViewPortHandler` holds information about the current bounds of the chart and it's drawing area.

```
ViewPortHandler handler = mChart.getViewPortHandler();

PointD topLeft = mChart.getValuesByTouchPoint(handler.contentLeft(), handler.contentTop(), YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
PointD bottomRight = mChart.getValuesByTouchPoint(handler.contentRight(), handler.contentBottom(), YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT);
```

After executing this, the `topLeft` point contains the minimum x-value and maximum y-value, the `bottomRight` point contains the maximum x-value and the minimum y-value.

The `AxisDependency` enum indicates from which axis you want to take the values from (in case you have both right and left `YAxis`).

Comment: left PointD, x: -0.0, y: 7.182112216949463 right PointD, x: 23.0, y: 0.0                But onValueSelected showing  x: 0 ,y: 1,0029 and od x:23 y:1,029.                          Btw. I asked for Y at start x: 0,0 and end x: 23,0 ( in this example).   not Y range from down to up (like on my screen but someone deleted it : )  https://scr.hu/5XWarD

Comment: Then it's even easier. Just use `dataSet.getEntryForXIndex(...)`